# I can't make a while loop for listen clients (socket) using a Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter

So, i'm creating a simple GUI in python for make a server who listen clients using socket module, but the program crashes.  Here's the code. I'm usin python 2.7.11

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket


def listen():
  global s
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.bind(("", 9999))
  s.listen(5)
  global c
  c = None
  while True:
    if c is None:
       box.insert(END,'[Esperando conexion...]')
       box.see(END)
       c, addr = s.accept()
       box.insert(END,'Conexion establecida desde: '+addr)
       box.see(END)
```

Comment: How are you calling that `listen` function? What's `box`? Is it a `Text` widget? Please consider making your code a [mcve], and include the full Traceback containing the error message.

Comment: I'm calling the function by a command integrated in a Button.              
conxsv =Button(ventcl, text = 'BUSCAR CLIENTE',command=listen, background ='SteelBlue1',width =22)                                                                       Theres no Traceback, the main window is freeze..

Comment: you cannot block the main loop like this.

Comment: Ok, so I guess your program does call `.mainloop`. But as Antti says, you can't run a tight `while` loop like that in a Tkinter program. You need to give Tkinter a chance to respond to events and to update the GUI. You _may_ be able to fix things by putting a call to `.update_idletasks` into your loop, but we really need more info about the structure of your code to give more specific advice.